# Alternative to hardcoding webapi urls in a MVC 4 ajax call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-web-api

I have deployed a mvc4 and web api 1 project to dev web server. The MVC4 web application will consume the webapi services. The url are the following:

**MVC 4:** dev.organization.org/QRT

**Web Api:** dev.organization.org/QRTService/api

(Both are deployed to the same web server and have the same domain)

```
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource": 'dev.organization.org/QRTService/api/ModifiedData',
"sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
"bDeferRender": true,
"bProcessing": true,
```

**Is there an alternative to hardcoding the fullurl, it makes it hard to move builds to different web servers and run locally?**

Comment: are you using the url.action helper?

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the webapi was inside the application QRT?

Comment: I would get QRT/api/someaction vs QRTService/api/someaction